# What is the difference between upgrading and renewing?

Tags: installation, upgrade

In this page:
http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

They suddenly start talking about "renewing" an ubuntu installation, but without a single explanation as to what they mean nor how to do it.

Could someone please explain that concept?

Comment: I looked at the page and find it a bit confusing myself. But we need to understand that it's a collaborative wiki edited by people with good intent but with differing linguistic backgrounds. I hope someone who is familiar with that wiki page steps up and makes the distinction clear.

Answer (score 1):

well just read more

"Renewing the Installation without formating the partitons (in contrast to upgrading), will also keep the personal data and configurations under /home but will renew all system settings under /etc as well as the default set of installed packages. "

Comment: I read more, and that is the one paragraph that puzzles me more.

Comment: What is renewing?, what is renewing without formatting?, how do you do both?, and why are they different to upgrading with or without fresh install? Don't you see?: The paragraph you copied does not explain the concept, nor the difference, nor how to renew, which is my question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a separate root partition as designated by:

```
/
```

& separate home partition as designated by:

```
/home
```

To renew you would uncheck the format option during installing so as ***not*** format home.  This as I understand will leave most of your personalisation intact.  Most People agree it is best to have a separate home and root setup for this very reason.  Root gets formatted whichever option you choose.

However I believe you would have had to of used advanced formatting option when installing your OS to have a separate home partition.  You can check with GParted (but you must never use GParted to run partitioning on a live/mounted environment, but rather only offline.)  This aside, GParted will show your partitioning structure if you are not sure.  It is possible to move home to it's own partition in a vanilla install, but that is not in the scope of this question, (IE; I do not know without Google!)